# A fixed number of decimal places with no decimal

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm trying to mask a decimal value.

I would like `19.76` to transform into `1976000`, or even `1976`

Another example would be `500.53` would become `50053000`.

I would like to do this with the `ToString` overloads rather than some kind of conversion method as it suits my xml settings file better.

I wasnt able to find an `IFormatProvider` that would not assume a decimal point, I suspect thats what I need however.

If I leave out the decimal in the string format like this:

```
?myvalue
19.76
?((decimal)myvalue).ToString("####000")
"020"
```

My value is rounded

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "masking"? Your one example is not sufficient for me to comprehend what you're trying to do.

Comment: @merlin2011 a string format is what i mean by mask.  Mask might be too an older term.  Basically I just want to be given a decimal value `(say 500.63)` remove the decimal and add 3 zeros using the `ToString` overloads to get `50063000`

Comment: And I suppose multiplying by `10^5` does not solve the problem?

Comment: It might, I was hoping that there was a string format that would accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you can't do it without converting the string to another format and removing the decimal separator.

There is no basic format that removes the decimal separator. Then you might try the built-in `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo` but it doesn't accept empty separators...

```
decimal d = 19.76m; 
var format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = string.Empty };
// ArgumentException: Decimal separator cannot be the empty string.
d.ToString(format);
```

Now all that's left is to implement `IFormatProvider` yourself... which will involve manually fiddling with the number to remove the decimal separator (convert to string and replace, multiply to make integer, etc.) anyway!

Comment: Well, this is the answer I was afraid of.  I'll do some rearchitecting to get around this stupid decimal format.  Your information on the NumberFormatInfo was excellent. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
string output = myValue.ToString().Replace(".", string.Empty);
```

At first you call the `ToString` method of your decimal value to get a string representation of it and later you replace the single `.` charecter of your string with the empty string.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZI6GU)

Comment: WOW!! never knew for `.NET` as well fiddle present.

Comment: @Rahul yeah it's pretty awesome. The first type of fiddle I learned about was the SQL fiddle - I learned it here in SO :). Then I searched to see if there was anything like this for `.NET` and I found it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah I know about it. It is alse awesome. Thanks for the comment.