# How to use string format to omit period but leave digits

Tags: c#, string, format, string-formatting

I have the format string `######.00` used for formatting decimals in C#. I need to change it so that it omits the period but keeps the digits following the period. Can I accomplish this just by changing the format? I've searched, but haven't been able to find a solution online.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31309178/1861453) to a very similar question, but it involves multiplying the decimal by 100 before formatting it. I'm not able to manipulate the number going in, nor the resulting string because I don't have access to them. This is because we're using a function from a third-party library that fetches the number from elsewhere and displays it formatted to the UI. I can only provide it with a format string. (If manipulating the number or resulting string is the only way to get it in the format we can probably do it, it would just take a good deal of refactoring, so I wanted to see if there's a simpler solution first. Hence the constraints.)

Just as an example of the output I'm looking for, consider the following code:

```
var myFormat = "{0:######.00}";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(myFormat, 1234.1234));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(myFormat, 5));
```

The code above currently outputs `1234.12` and `5.00`, but I would like it to output `123412` and `500` just by changing `myFormat`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you manipulate the number or resulting string? Are you able to use a different overload of `string.Format`?

Comment: `I'm not able to manipulate the number, nor the resulting string, only the format string.` Can you talk us through that constraint? **Why** is that the only tool you have?

Comment: @mjwills P2 leaves the decimal in, as well as the percent. I was thinking along the lines of `{0:#%}` as well, but I'm guessing the remaining `%` sign is a deal breaker.

Comment: why not simply multiply by 100 and take the `int` part instead of using string format ?

Comment: @yiabiten Read the second paragraph of the question

Comment: @DavidG my bad: jumped straight to the code.

Comment: @DavidG I can't manipulate the number going in or the string coming out because I don't have direct access to them. I've updated my question explaining why.

Comment: @mjwills I can't manipulate the number going in or the string coming out because I don't have direct access to them. I've updated my question explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the format string is what you can change, there's probably no way to remove the dot.
However, you can implement your own [Formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#example-a-custom-formatting-operation), as MSDN's example.

```
string.Format(new CustomerFormatter(), "{0}", 1234.1234)
```

Comment: I just tried creating a custom `NumberFormatInfo` but "`Decimal separator cannot be the empty string`" Also, this answer agrees with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664360/a-fixed-number-of-decimal-places-with-no-decimal

Comment: I think you're right about there not being a way to accomplish what I want using only the format string (I haven't found a way yet). Using a CustomFormatter may be the solution for us that involves the least amount of refactoring though, so thank you for the answer. 